# Opening and viewing a large number of websites in miniature screens

Tags: php, excel, vba

As I receive thousands of URLs to be added to our firewall blacklist every day, I find it impossible to verify which deserve blacklisting. As a result, I receive hundreds of complaints that good sites were blocked. So in order for me to test any URL I have to open it in a browser that is in front of the firewall. For hundreds of thousands of urls this is really impossible.

Therefore, I thought of an Excel macro or a VBA application that can be developed which will take a list of e.g. 1000 URLs at a time and opens them all as something like a photo gallery with each screen as 175 x 130, filling the displaying monitor. Each opened screen can be ticked to be selected for deletion. On deletion of selected screens, the originating URLs are also deleted from the providing list.

The outcome of this process is a shorter and "genuine" blacklist that will eliminate users complaints. This solution was just the outcome of my thinking (and suffering!). Is it possible? If not, I welcome any other solution that will facilitate viewing thousands of miniature sites that can be selectively selected for deletion if they should not be blacklisted.

Comment: This isn't suitable for Excel/VBA - I'd say something like a web application would be better, plus a server-based browser component to render sites (Webkit maybe) in a background job to PNG image thumbnails. It would, of course, be well worth your time thoroughly researching this, in case someone has done it before.

Comment: (Btw, this is probably a bit off-topic here, since although it _could_ involve programming, it doesn't currently do so. If you do try to build this yourself, and ask a question involving code, then that will be very on topic!)

Comment: My apologies as I always think to ask experts first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might actually be able to do this with Excel if you use some other service to take the snapshots for you.

Basically, you need a snapshotting server.  Given the volume, I suggest building your own.  This is actually very easy to do with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).  You write a small script that accepts a URL as a parameter.  PhantomJS renders the page and returns a screenshot.  You should be able to add images by URL to your Excel sheet, which allows this all to work.

Ideally though, you would make your own web application to do this, but the snapshotting could work the same way.

Comment: Thank you Brad for your precious answer. I believe it provides an ideal solution for my question.